# Is there a way to redeem a promo code from within the app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, promotion-code

Since beginning of this year, it's possible to use promo codes for apps: [Create promotions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495)

As described on the page [In-app Promotions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html), promo codes can also be redeemed from within the app.

It also says "You can also keep a SKU off the Play Store, so the only way to get that item is by entering that SKU's promo code.".

That's what I want for an in app product: Only let a user get an in app product by entering the promo code within the app and do not allow to buy it with money.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

By analyzing the Play Store app I found out that the current version opens the "Redeem your code" dialog with the following intent:

```
try {
  final Uri redeemUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/redeem");
  final Intent redeemIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, redeemUri);
  startActivity(redeemIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  // Play Store app is not installed
}
```

Please note that this may change in any new version of Play Store.

Comment: This automatically enters the code in the dialog: https://play.google.com/redeem?code=YOURCODE. Now you can create your own dialog if you want to.

Comment: This doesn't work. Still same error
That code didn't work. Try again. If the code is for a specific app, redeem it in that app

This error is coming

Comment: @AliRaza do you know the solution.I am having the same error for redeem code within the app

Comment: @SheetalSavani, no still no solution on this. The only way is to redeem the code through Play Store app. If you find any solution, please remember to post it here too. Thank you.

Comment: I still can't redeem code from my Android app. And if I try to redeem code from Google Play app, I get error: "That code didn't work. Try again. If the code is for a specific app, redeem it in that app".