# How to insert promo code inside my android application to buy items?

Tags: android, google-play, promotion-code

I have implemented InApp Purchases in my app and works correctly. Now want to use promo code to get items freely.

In documentation it says: *Your app should allow users to redeem promo codes inside the app itself. If your app supports the in-app purchase workflow (described in Making In-app Billing requests), your app automatically supports in-app redemption of promo codes. When you launch the in-app purchase UI, the user has the option to pay for the purchase with a promo code.* https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html

`But in my application there is not any option to select for promo code. There is only buy option. How can user insert promo code inside app?`

These images from PlayStore app. There is `Redeem` dialog looks like peyment dialog. It is possible to open it from play store app as described in this article and on following images. I can insert my promo code follwing this flow and it works.  http://www.greenbot.com/article/3043048/android/how-to-redeem-a-google-play-store-promo-code.html.
[image] 
[image: Redeem dialog]

Comment: checkout [this link](https://hackernoon.com/inapp-subscription-setup-and-testing-v3-api-android-8239534b3e79#.l9avdqhqn) so you get an idea how `IAB` works

Comment: I have already implemented in app billing in my app and it works with peyment and promo codes. I want to insert promo code inside my app. This does not help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve, but what i understood is that you want to create your own promo code view inside app. If that is the case, you have to create a custom view and API which supports your promotion code logic

Comment: I want to use standart view (as shown above image) not custom. I want to call to open it from my app.

Comment: Well if you have implemented inside app, it should open from your app. If you check the link i give you above, it is opened from the app and not outside it. Update your question as it is not clear what are you trying to achieve exactly

Comment: There is image to subscribe In your link not redeem your code. They are different things. I want user insert its promo code for purchase item freely not pay for it.

Comment: Than as i said: your backend (API) should implement the logic. You send the promo code to your API. When APi receives it it updates relevant fields.

Answer (score 6):

In this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999817/is-there-a-way-to-redeem-a-promo-code-from-within-the-app) your found solution

Adapt the code

```
String code = "request code with dialog"
try {
    String url = "https://play.google.com/redeem?code=" + URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8");
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  // Play Store app is not installed
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When the user click on buy button, in the list of payment methods, exist an option to redeem a promo code, you can send to your user the code and he can redeem it using this payment method in the payment flow or he can reddem it going to the Play Store and click redeem, there your user should insert the promo code an follow the stepts to redeem it

Comment: this option is not available, you can choose only cards

Comment: Still this "redeem code" option is not available, only cards are visible & can be added & picked.