# In-app purchases doesn't show "enter promo code" as an option

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Here's how I perform an in-app purchase .

```
public static void purchaseInApp(String sku) throws RemoteException, SendIntentException{
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = billingService.getBuyIntent(3, PACKAGE_NAME,
                sku, "inapp", "");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
            activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                    PERFORM_PURCHASE_REMOVE_ADS, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                    Integer.valueOf(0));
}
```

I have issued 500 promocodes, but option to enter promocodes doesn't show. I think it shown for about 1 day and then stopped. I had this issue with 2 apps on different accounts. may be I did something wrong with the code?

Here's screenshot (sorry, it's in Russian) . No promocode option

[image]

Comment: Any solution for this? I also don't see, only credit card option is available

Comment: @Zotyi I've found that pre promo code is only available for a current version. Once you've changed, for example, version from 1 to 2 - promo codes will disappear as a pay option

Comment: Hmm...might be. What I did, just move the user to the direct promo purchase URL, that is even more professional. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999817/is-there-a-way-to-redeem-a-promo-code-from-within-the-app